# Javascript - Difference dates with 120s

Tags: momentjs

I need to show difference between now and now+120 seconds. I need too compare difference in seconds, not in minutes. The code looks like

```
 this.nextDate = moment().add(120, 'seconds');

 this.timer = setInterval(() => {
     this.currentDate = moment();
     this.diff = moment.duration(this.nextDate.diff(this.currentDate));    
 }, 1000)
```

The problem: *Console.log(this.diff.seconds())* return that difference is 60 seconds (and going down), not 120.

So: What´s the problem? Why *moment.js* doesn´t get 120s?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problem:

1. In `moment.duration()` if you pass just one parameter by default it is the number of milliseconds, so you can moltiply the number for `1000` `(moment.duration(diff * 1000))` or you can pass a second parameter indicating the type of time unit like this `moment.duration(diff, 'seconds')` or passing an object instead of two paramters like `moment.duration({ seconds: diff })`.
2. the second problem is the function for extract the seconds from the duration object, you used `.seconds()` that it return a number between 0 and 59, if you want the length of the duration in seconds you must use `.asSeconds()`

For me the duration it's a plus in this case, you can use a simple countdown of second like that:

```js
const nextDate = moment().add(120, 'seconds');

const timer = setInterval(() => {
     const currentDate = moment();
     const seconds = nextDate.diff(currentDate, 'seconds');    
     
     console.log(seconds);
 }, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

Else you want or you need to use duration this is the code:

```js
const nextDate = moment().add(120, 'seconds');

const timer = setInterval(() => {
  const currentDate = moment();
  const seconds = nextDate.diff(currentDate, 'seconds');

  const duration = moment.duration(nextDate.diff(currentDate, 'seconds'), 'seconds'); // Alternatively const duration = moment.duration({ seconds });

  console.log('duration: ', duration.asSeconds());
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```